# Memory consumption for Spark SQL with aggregation function

Tags: memory, apache-spark, garbage-collection, hive, apache-spark-sql

I have a hive table with few bigint or string columns, over 38 million rows, total size is slightly over 1GB, test environment is a small standalone cluster with 4 worker nodes and each has 8GB memory, Spark 1.4.
From Spark-sql shell, I tried to execute a SQL

```
create table bla as select user_id, brand_id, sum(cnt) from foo group by user_id, brand_id
```

several times and the job always got stuck in the first stage with few tasks hanging.

GC report seems indicate that there is not enough memory to store the transient objects and the process is waiting for full GC to finish.

GC output from one hanging node:

> 4572.821: [GC [PSYoungGen: 1707488K->595392K(1963136K)] 5871286K->5321918K(7555584K), 1.2474880 secs] [Times: user=16.32 sys=0.43, real=1.25 secs] 
>   4575.891: [GC [PSYoungGen: 1739840K->559488K(1970304K)] 6466366K->5882382K(7562752K), 0.9950000 secs] [Times: user=12.69 sys=0.72, real=1.00 secs] 
>   4576.886: [Full GC

My question is: Does my sql really need  more than 32GB memory to run against 1GB data? or  are there quick optimization settings that I just missed? 
I could get the sql executed successfully with less amount of records, 
or even with full data, if I avoid sum/avg in the query, queries like

```
select user_id, brand_id, count(cnt)
```

or

```
select user_id, brand_id, concat(xx)
```

all work and the memory footprint on each node never exceed 1 or 2GB after GC.

Second question: The initial stage always use 10 partitions, how to change the parallelism?

Thanks
Wanchun

Answer (score 1):

Just want to give an update, I really believe current spark release has an suboptimal implementation on some of its aggregation functions. e.g. if I just replace the sum() with count() or max() in the query, then the query come back successfully in 30-40 seconds. 
Eventually I made sum() query working by double the workers, thus with twice the memory the job completed within 3 minutes.
Out of curiosity of Tungsten, I built spark1.5 out of the source, fire up the same query that took 3 minutes in spark1.4, finish time is the range of 40 to 55 seconds. 
Cheers,
Wanchun

Answer (score 0):

To your specific questions:

- How much memory Spark needs depends on your data and the operations you perform on it. In your particular case, the larger the unique `GROUP BY` aggregates, the greater the memory overhead. Also note that JVM data structures are, in general, very memory inefficient. See [this presentation](http://www.slideshare.net/cnbailey/memory-efficient-java) for some details. Last but not least you have to be careful about comparing sizes. Is the table 1Gb on disk? Is it using an optimized format with automatic compressions such as Parquet?
- There are two ways to change the parallelism. First, you can change the number of input files. Second, you can explicitly repartition the data using `repartition(numPartitions)`. Look for this method in the [RDD doc](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD).

You can repartition programmatically based on the number of existing partitions to achieve the desired level of parallelism or data file granularity, e.g.,

```
val df = ctx.jsonFile("file://...")
df.repartition(10 * df.rdd.partitions.size)
```

By using `df.rdd.partitions.size` you can also adjust the number of partitions dynamically based on your cluster size, e.g., to get the number of partitions to be, say, 4x the number of executor CPUs, etc.

If you are experiencing memory problems, increasing the number of partitions is a good starting point for finding a processing pipeline that works within the constraints of your cluster.

There are other memory-related optimizations:

- If you run out of memory during a reduce phase, you may want to increase `spark.shuffle.memoryFraction`
- If your operations would not benefit from caching, you could reduce `spark.storage.memoryFraction`.

More about [configuring Spark](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html).